# Maintaining file permissions across SVN updates?

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, file-permissions

I have a series of python scripts with execute permissions in Linux.  They are stored in SVN.

If I then run `svn up` to update them, the overwritten files are back to 644 - ie no execute permissions for anyone.

Yes I could just script it to `chmod +x *` afterwards, but surely there's a way to store permissions in SVN or to maintain them when you update?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to set the svn:executable property on the file.

```
svn propset svn:executable true  <filename>
```

Comment: @Mark Can you update your reference to a more recent documentation reference. Subversion 1.1 is a bit old and the documentation has improved since then. E.g. to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.html

Comment: Ah, well spotted, thanks, I've deleted.  Thanks again to Daniel, and here's a link to the propset:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html - yours was to advanced propset.

Comment: Well, OK, I know `svn:executable` for the +x bit, but what about outer permissions (read-only, etc.).

Comment: Setting the value to "true" is a bit mis-leading, because for this magical property, Subversion will actually set the value to * (asterisk character), and that is what you will get if you propget immediately after setting it.